# How to edit text like this under VSCode and Sublime Text3? What is this function called?

Tags: visual-studio-code, sublime-text-3, text-editing

This is my GIF recorded in Pycharm:

[image: This is my GIF recorded in Pycharm.]

How can I click anywhere to enter text like this?

Comment: Are you sure there wasn't already whitespace text there? The fact the line numbers are shown seems to indicate that the lines you write on already have content

Comment: Without text, I press Enter multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature is called [Virtual Space](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/visualstudio/ide/how-to-manage-editor-modes?view=vs-2017) in VS and is not available in VS Code yet

- [Does VS code support virtual space?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37379497/995714)
- [Virtual Space is not implemented](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/13960)